# Is an API language specific

Tags: api, bing-api

This is probably a pretty basic question, but are APIs language specific.  In General, do certain languages only work with certain APIs or should any language be able to talk to any API.

Specifically, Bing Webmaster Tools API has code example in C#.  Does that mean I can't access the API in Python?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, it just means Microsoft makes both of them (Bing and C#).

Comment: A general answer to this question will depend greatly on both the platform and the actual API under discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an API is exposed via HTTP and returns a language-neutral format like JSON or XML (which most popular third-party APIs do) then there's no restriction on what programming language you can use to parse the API responses.

Some API providers may provide specific client libraries e.g,. The Facebook JavaScript SDK, but this doesn't preclude using a different language, it just means you'll get less support in doing so.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I have one question, is there different ways API can be exposed? if yes why would everyone expose it via HTTP since it is language-neutral? is it because of security issues?

Answer (score 2):

An API always relates to just one language. However, sometimes interfaces or libraries are created so that they can be accessed by other languages. For example, XML is used for specifying listings in ebay. It is uploaded via HTTP. However there are many libraries, such as for PHP and Java, that abstract that into their terms, but keep a direct correlation between their usage and the XML they send.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Many APIs are designed for use with one particular language, for example functionality provided by a PHP framework. Having said that, it does not necessarily mean that in the future another language could start using them; for example IronPython making use of the .NET Framework.

It is very common for compiled libraries to be used by multiple languages, e.g. graphics libraries.

You can also have web-service based APIs (e.g. Bing in your example) which respond to HTTP requests. These could be invoked by any language, or *anything* in general.